# Residue calculation for Eulerian expansion of the cotangent

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

I am looking for ideas on proving the Eulerian expansion of the cotangent using residue calculation: $$\pi\cot(\pi z)=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{z+n}+\frac{1}{z-n}\right), \ z\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Although your question is about the cotangent function and complex analysis, the tag “cotangent-complex” is actually not suitable since that means something else entirely: see  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotangent_complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The residue approach to the partial fraction expansion of $\cot(z)$ is explained in Freitag & Busam's "Complex Analysis", Prop. III.7.13, and probably in other books as well.

Here is a more general result regarding partial fraction expansions:

**Proposition:** Let $f \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{C})$ and let $(\gamma_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of shrinking rectifiable loops that avoid the poles of $f$ and whose interiors exhaust $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $\gamma_n$ is in the interior of $\gamma_{n+1}$. If
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_n} \frac{|f(z)| |dz|}{|z|} = 0,
$$
then
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{p_k \in A_n} P_k\bigg(\frac{1}{z-p_k}\bigg),
$$
where $A_n :=$ interior of $\gamma_n$ $\setminus$ closure of the interior of $\gamma_{n-1}$ is the $n$-th open "annulus", $p_k$ are the poles of $f$ lying in the respective open annulus and $P_k$ are the corresponding principal parts.

*Proof:* Apply the residue theorem for each $\gamma_n$ and use the vanishing condition to ensure (compact) convergence. $\square$